# Why Ruby template handler isn't called in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

What could be the reason that the following Ruby template handler isn't called in my Rails 4 application? The returned json contains all the fields that a Job has, instead of just `id` and `date` fields.

```
# app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
...
def index
  @jobs = Job.all
  render json: @jobs
end
...


# app/views/jobs/index.json.ruby
jobs = @jobs.map |job| do
  {
    id: job.id,
    date: job.created_at
  }
end

jobs.to_json
```

I use Rails 4.0.0.rc1 and ruby 1.9.3p0.

Comment: Can you edit this with comma inside of hash ?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not calling a template handler. Instead, what Rails does here is call `@jobs.as_json` which returns a Hash containing with the attributes of that model. On this hash, it then calls `to_json` and return the result to the client.

The normal course of action is to override `as_json` on your model instead of using a template. As said above, `as_json` should return a hash that contains only the information you'd like to return to the user. Rails will then just serialize this hash as JSON.